# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError thrown, using ngIf to check form control

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have an Angular application, and implemented a search bar in the header of the page (which is basically a form with an input text). I want to include an 'x' button in the input, so that I can reset its text. That button should only appear when the input has text. The first solution I found was to change the input type to 'search', but that didn't work out as I expected. After that I manually added the button and used the *ngIf directive to check if the formControl has any values.

```
<button *ngIf="searchTerm.value" pButton type="reset"
        class="iwp-icon-gen_close_l reset-button"
        [izDisabled]="isDisabled$ | async"
        (click)="resetSearchTerm()"
></button>
```

In my component the code is like this:

```
// The user input in the full text search input field.
searchTerm = new FormControl('');

ngOnInit() {
    this.filterService.filter$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(filter => this.searchTerm.setValue(filter.searchTerm));
}
```

When the page is loading, it throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError, which I know it can be solved by encapsulating the code inside ngOnInit with setTimeOut(fn, 0), but I'm trying to figure out a 'clean' way to do this. Can somebody help me ?

Comment: FYI it says `[izDisabled]` - not sure if it's a typo

Comment: Max has a great resource on it - https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4